# globalToLocal method in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an arrow inside a tooltip and the tooltip is positioned absolute and I have a div that when you rollover it, it revels a tooltip. I want the arrow to show right over the div. In AS3 I used to use LocalToGlobal to find the correct position. How to implement a globalToLocal and localToGlobal function in jquery?

IS there anyone who can help with this. It's starting to drive me a little crazy.
My post below explains it a little better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but not sure how event.pageX; would give me the position. It gives me the position of the rollover div but the tooltip arrow is not at that position. Remember the arrow is inside the tooltip so say the position of the div is 622 and the position of the tooltip is 411 and the arrow of the tooltip at left side of the tooltip would be 0. So if I was to set the arrow to the divs position then it would be way outside the tooltip and not shown.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the coordinates of the element

```
$("element").hover(function (event){ //just change the eventlistener according to your needs
  var coordinate1 = event.pageY;
  var coordinate2 = event.pageX;
  var coordinate3 = event.clientY;
  var coordinate4 = event.clientX;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, You want to get the position. You can use [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method for this. It gets the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent. See the example in the docs.

## From the DOCs

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of
> an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with
> .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the
> document. When positioning a new element near another one and within
> the same containing DOM element, .position() is the more useful.
>
> Returns an object containing the properties top and left.